# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: when using cursor in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-asynctask

I am using Cursor to get data from DB (it's information about the overlay markers on Map). I am loading a map with help of this data. Interaction with the DB through Cursor is done in a asyncTask.

Now here is the problem I am facing. If I press back button while the cursor is running to load the map (i.e. in middle of loading overlay markers in a while loop) I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery (mSql = SELECT _id, category, latitude, longitude FROM node)
```

Here is the complete trace of it:

```
12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824):     at  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)
 12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery (mSql = SELECT _id, category, latitude, longitude FROM node) 
 12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:34)
12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:64)
12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:299)
12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.onMove(SQLiteCursor.java:271)
12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:188)
12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext(AbstractCursor.java:256)
12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824):     at org.mid.kew.activities.MapPageActivity$MapLoadingAsyncTask.doInBackground(MapPageActivity.java:632)
12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824):     at org.mid.kew.activities.MapPageActivity$MapLoadingAsyncTask.doInBackground(MapPageActivity.java:1)
12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-21 11:11:30.173: E/AndroidRuntime(2824):     ... 4 more
```

and here is a snapshot of code I am using in asyncTask

Under DoInBackground method

```
openKewDataBase();
Cursor cursor = getCursorForOverLayIcons();
startManagingCursor(cursor);
cursor.moveToFirst();
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            ...

    cursor.moveToNext();
}

cursor.close();
```

Under onPostExecute Method

```
....

closeKewDataBase();
```

As per I can trace Its crashing at "cursor.moveToNext();"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are manually closing the cursor with `cursor.close()`, you shouldn't call `startManagingCursor(cursor)`. You need to choose one or the other.

As you are doing this in an `AsyncTask`, you almost certainly don't want the enclosing `Activity` to manage the cursor for you, as the `AsyncTask` can outlive the `Activity`. So just do it manually.

(I presume the `AsyncTask` is an inner class of your `Activity`.)

Comment: Problem Solved... Thank you Graham Borland

Comment: Hi Graham i am facing the same problem.. could you check [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633581/attempt-to-re-open-an-already-closed-object-java-lang-illegalstateexception/11633761#comment15427898_11633761) please.